# How to reformulate multiple trait bounds as a single trait?

Tags: rust, traits

I have a working library of mathematical functions. My issue is that many of the functions with generic types have verbose trait bounds. For example:

```rust
fn some_operation<T>(a: &T, b: &T) -> T 
where
           T: PartialOrd + Signed + Clone + Zero + One + Sum,
  for<'a> &T: Add<&'a T, Output = T>
            + Sub<&'a T, Output = T>
            + Mul<&'a T, Output = T>
            + Div<&'a T, Output = T>
{
// ops
}
```

I have tried to declare a generic trait including these in the following way:

```rust
pub trait ReferencedFieldOps<T>
where 
   for<'a> &'a T: Add<&'a T, Output = T>
                + Sub<&'a T, Output = T>
                + Mul<&'a T, Output = T>
                + Div<&'a T, Output = T>,
{}
```

So that I can restate my operation to:

```rust
fn some_operation<T>(a: &T, b: &T) -> T 
where T: PartialOrd + Signed + Clone + Zero + One + Sum + ReferencedFieldOps<T>
{ 
//ops
}
```

But this won't compile. I get many `no implementation for &'a T + &'a T` or similar for other - * / etc. Even though when this was explicitly typed in the first instance there was no issue. ***Is this the correct way to do this?***

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0f1c3e55f5fd7f1bbdd80804f5a41f46 ? plz do [mre]

Comment: A minimal example that tries to do this but fails is: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8ada142904913d5161cfd285369eb6bc

Comment: Note that `for<'a> &'a T: Add<&'a T, Output = T>` becomes `T: ReferencedFieldOps<T>`, which implies `T: for<'a> Add<&'a T, Output = T>`. Do you see the problem?

Comment: It looks like the Add operations is not being explicitly defined between two references of the same type, but instead between one value and one reference. I don't understand why this isn't accounted for given the trait definition is explicit.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know a way to do this in stable Rust but, if you want you can try out [`trait_alias`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/41517) experimental feature:

```rust
#![feature(trait_alias)]
use core::ops::*;

struct My {
    val: f64,
}

impl<'a> Add<&'a My> for &'a My {
    type Output = My;
    fn add(self, other: &My) -> My {
        My {
            val: (self.val + other.val),
        }
    }
}

pub trait ReferencedFieldOps<T, U> = where T: Add<T, Output = U>;

fn some_operation<T, U>(a: T, b: T) -> U
where
    (): ReferencedFieldOps<T, U>,
{
    a + b
}

fn main() {
    let a = My { val: 2.0 };
    let b = My { val: 2.5 };
    assert_eq!(some_operation(&a, &b).val, 4.5)
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=934c8f83331a4c60a35f54e0c23bde29)

Comment: Thanks, very helpful. Not sure I'm yet good enough to be trying out experimental features but will aspire to be soon!